# Simple JQuery Form Submission with ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-plugins, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a very basic email submission form in my ASP.NET MVC 3 app. I'm trying to integrate the jQuery form plug-in with it.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.form.js")"></script> 

<script type="text/javascript">
// prepare the form when the DOM is ready 
$(document).ready(function () {
    var options = {
        beforeSubmit:  showRequest,
        success: showResponse
    };

    // bind form using 'ajaxForm' 
    $('#mailform').ajaxForm(options);
});
function showRequest(formData, jqForm, options) {
    alert('request');
}
// post-submit callback
function showResponse(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form) {
    alert('response');
}
</script> 
...
<form action="@Url.Action("SubmitEmail")" class="mail-form" id="mailform" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <span class="txt">
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="Enter Your Email Address" />
        </span>
        <input class="button" id="submitemail" type="submit" />
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

I've tested my non-AJAX version and it works just fine. When I try to use the jQuery plug-in, however, the `showRequest` function gets called, but the `showResponse` function doesn't-- and it doesn't seem like the method is ever called on the server either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple things to check - you have a script tag for jQuery form but I don't see one for jQuery itself (you'd want to have jQuery listed before the plugin).

Also - install Fiddler or Firebug and make sure that requests are being sent out. And just to throw this out there, for a call this simple the form plugin is overkill. $.post would work just fine.

Comment: Thanks Andy. I went ahead and just used the $.post approach.